# I am trying to build a .NET Core web app that connects to a SAML Identity Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, saml-2.0

I created a simple .NET Core web app to connect to a SAML 2.0 identity provider to test single sign-on. I want the user to be able to goto to my app, enter in their IdP username and password, and then connect to my system.

I found some tutorials and found this code which I am trying to use in my project.

However, whenever I run it, I get this error:

> Signature must be in the SAML Response Assertion

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong...does anyone see anything bad in the code?  It builds just fine.

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Http;
using Kentor.AuthServices;
using Kentor.AuthServices.Configuration;
using Kentor.AuthServices.WebApi;

namespace YourWebApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/auth")]
    public class AuthController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _samlConfig;

        public AuthController()
        {
            _samlConfig = new SAML2Configuration();
            _samlConfig.SigningCertificate = CertificateHelper.GetCertificate();
            _samlConfig.AllowedAudienceUris.Add("https://yourwebapi.com"); 
            _samlConfig.Load();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("login")]
        public IHttpActionResult Login()
        {
            var authServices = new AuthServices(_samlConfig);
            var commandResult = authServices.CommandFactory.GetLoginCommand(Request);

            return commandResult.Execute() as IHttpActionResult;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("acs")]
        public IHttpActionResult AssertionConsumerService()
        {
            var authServices = new AuthServices(_samlConfig);
            var commandResult = authServices.CommandFactory.GetAcsCommand(Request);

            if (commandResult.EntityId != null)
            {
                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                    commandResult.Claims.Select(c => new Claim(c.ClaimType, c.Value)),
                    "SAML2");

                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var jwtToken = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: "YourIssuer", 
                    audience: "YourAudience", 
                    subject: claimsIdentity,
                    signingCredentials: new X509SigningCredentials(_samlConfig.SigningCertificate));

                var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(jwtToken);

                return Ok(token);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid SAML assertion");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you pls let us know which identity provider you are integrating into your app?

Comment: @TinyWang The identity provider is just a client of ours.  They are using SAML 2.0.  The tech guys there say they provide SSO for hundreds of other clients successfully so it must be something I am doing wrong.

Comment: oh, that sounds wonderful, and you may ask your team how to configuration/integrate that service.. normally, we followed the tutorial provided by the identity provider to manage the code.... I can't say there's any wrong in your code...